# Exporting stored procedure result to excel sheet

Tags: sql, sql-server

[Exporting stored procedure result to excel with column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831198/exporting-stored-procedure-result-to-excel-with-column-name)

I looked at the link above and created stored procedure. I am not getting data into ExcelSheet I have created in D:\testing.xls and D:\data_file.xls

```
Errors List

1.usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]
NULL

2.The system cannot find the file specified.
NULL

3.Could Not Find D:\data_file.xls
NULL
```

Comment: How did you call the stored procedure you created? What did you try?

Comment: EXEC proc_generate_excel_with_columns 'master','sys','employee','D:\testing.xls'

Answer (score 0):

Well may be following script will be useful to you.

```
INSERT INTO OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Data Source={\\Operations\Output\CR_20071130.xls};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0')..
[Sheet1$A1:H1] exec YourStoredProcedure
```